windows 11 non-admin user IIS Pool access issue in local machine
By creating a non-admin user in Windows 11 home edition. This user is also assigned to the administrative group and additionally I allowed him full control over inetsrv

%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv

folder, after logging in with this user and running this command from CMD

%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd list apppool /name:poolname/text:state

Results show : Unknown. But "poolname" is a pool running.

%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:poolname

The result shows : "ERROR ( message:The WAS service is not available - try starting the service first. )".
But a "WAS" is running.

All IIS management tools were designed to be run by administrators. Don’t bother otherwise.

@LexLi, I assigned this user to the Administrators group. But the result is the same

Please edit the question first.

Do you have any problem now? The error above has nothing to do with permissions.

@samwu
Yes, I getting problem when I call pool status/start/stop. But this user group member show Administrators group already assigned.

According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. What problem are you having? Is this the error above? Do you want to resolve this error?

According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. What problem are you having? Is this the error above? Do you want to resolve this error?
